# Find rows in one table that have no corresponding row in another table SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to get certain records from one table that don't exist in another by multiple fields. For example, if I have table 1 like:

```
 Account    Animal
 123    dog
 456    cat
 789    bird
```

And table 2 like:

```
Account Animal
123 cat
456 cat
```

What I want the final table to be is:

```
Account Animal
123 dog
```

Here is what I tried:

select 
     a.*
from
     table1 left join table2
     on a.account=b.account and a.animal=b.animal
where
     b.animal is null

Comment: What happened to the bird? What's wrong with your current query?

Comment: I guess the bird would still be on there.

Comment: @ali.hash2 Then don't use `LEFT JOIN` if you don't want the bird.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want where the *accounts* match but the animals are not the same.

This suggests an inner join and filtering:

```
select a.*
from table1 a join
     table2 b
     on a.account = b.account 
where a.animal <> b.animal ;
```

This works for your sample data, but it does make assumptions about not having duplicates.